# Metirial-UI custom-paginator dynamic componentProps

Tags: reactjs, datagrid, material-ui, paginator

I have implemented **custom paginator** to the DataGrid in mui/x-data-grid as explained in the [documentation](https://material-ui.com/components/data-grid/components/).

However i have added small code part to handle the pagination efficiently and it was required to access some **state in the  main component**.

It looks like we only can pass custom properties on initial render. can any one tell me how to pass dynamic state values to this custom paginator

CustomPaginator.js

Here **props.resetGrid** and **props.data** properties need to be dynamically change while using app

```
import {Pagination} from "@material-ui/lab";
import React from "react";
import {useDispatch} from "react-redux";
import ServiceHub from "cg-service-hub/ServiceHub";
import {useGridSlotComponentProps} from '@mui/x-data-grid';

const CustomPagination =(props) => {
const dispatch = useDispatch()
const sh = ServiceHub();
const { state, apiRef } = useGridSlotComponentProps();
const maxRecords = props.pageSize;
const [visitedPages,setVisitedPages] = React.useState([]);

const handleChangePage = (event, value) => {
    let page = value-1
    if(**props.resetGrid**){
        setVisitedPages([]);
    }
    if (visitedPages.indexOf(page)===-1){
        let tv = [...visitedPages];
        tv.push(page);
        setVisitedPages(tv);
        let headers = {...{'max-records': maxRecords, 'last-record':(page * maxRecords)}, ...props.headers}
        dispatch(props.getter({...sh.getParams, url:props.url,  headers:headers , callBackHandler: props.callBackHandler, showSnackbar: false }))
    }
    apiRef.current.setPage(page)
};

return (
    <Pagination showFirstButton showLastButton
        color="primary"
        count={state.pagination.pageCount}
        page={state.pagination.page + 1}
        onChange={handleChangePage}
    />
);
}

export  default CustomPagination;
```

data grid

```
  <DataGrid autoHeight pagination
                  rows={gridData.data}
                  columns={columns}
                  pageSize={gridData.pageSize}
                  rowCount={gridData.trc}
                  checkboxSelection
                  disableSelectionOnClick
                  onSelectionModelChange = {(newSelectionModel) => {
                      setRowsToDelete(newSelectionModel);
                  }}
                  selectionModel={rowsToDelete}
                  onCellClick={params => { if(params.colDef.field === 'edit') openModal(params.row, CONSTANT.ACTIONS.EDIT)}}
                  components={{
                      Pagination: CustomPagination,
                  }}
                  componentsProps={{
                      pagination: {
                          **resetGrid: gridData.resetGrid**,
                          pageSize: gridData.pageSize,
                          getter: getVehicle,
                          url: ENDPOINT.VEHICLE,
                          headers: {},
                          callBackHandler: CONSTANT.CALLBACK_ACTIONS.VEHICLE,
                          **data: {text_search: textSearchRef.current}**
                      }
                  }}
        />
```

Comment: You say that if  **resetGrid: gridData.resetGrid** prop in data grid change the data grid component will not render so the pagination props will not change? are you sure that the dynamic props reference changes ?

Comment: As a solution I think you can separate pagination from datagrid completely and handle page change or any other data handler in a top level container that passes data to data grid. this way you can better control over your components and props

Comment: @HDM91 yes, properties are change through application. and as you suggested now i'm working on separating this pagination from data grid. i think that would work.